# C++ - How can I find vector<int> in vector<vector<int>> with STL algorithm function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a vector of vector of int that contains some data, say

```
[ [1,2,3],  [7,9] ]
```

And there is a vector, say `a`.
I want to find out if vector `a` is in that vector of vector.  How can I do that?

Comment: Use [`std::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find)? Or just a plain loop comparing each vector to `a`?

Comment: But it seems vector doesn’t overwrite the operator ==,

Comment: @Stephen.W [yes, it does](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_cmp)

Answer (score 3):

```
std::find(std::begin(to_search), std::end(to_search), to_find);
```

Returns an iterator to the position of `to_find` in `to_search`, or `to_search::end()` if not contained.